# Rails can't see .rjs file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I'm trying to learn how to use AJAX in my rails apps so i've decided to start with something simple. I have a blog app on which user can vote on any blog post. Here is my code for `posts#vote`:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  (...)
  def vote
    post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if current_user.voted_on?(post)
      current_user.unvote_for(post)
    else
      current_user.vote_for(post)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(post) }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

and here is a link code for my `posts#view`:

**view.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Vote", vote_post_path(post.id), :remote => true %>
```

And now, if i'll click my `Vote` link, `posts#vote` action works and vote is casted, however i'm getting an error:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template posts/vote,
>   application/vote with {:handlers=>[:haml, :coffee, :erb, :builder],
>   :locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html]}.

I have (empty) `vote.rjs` file in my `views/posts` folder but for some reason rails can't see it. According to error, the only file extensions that rails is searchng for are `.haml`, `.coffee`, `.erb` and `.builder`. Shouldn't there be also a `.rjs` extension on that list? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use prototype.js instead of jquery and install prototype-rails if you want .rjs support back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file should be called `vote.js.erb`. Rails doesn't use a `.rjs` extension.

Answer (score 1):

The `.rjs` extension was originally used for `Rails` and `Prototype` JS library.

With `Rails 3.1` the default library was switched to JQuery.

If you want to use `.rjs` in your Rails project it would mean using Prototype instead of JQuery. The gem for that is [prototype-rails](https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails).